# How to minimize SQL calls from the back-end and yet keep it and the front-end syncronized with correct data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Consider I have

1. A DB with companies and contact persons,
2. A Web API

> /Companies/{id?}
>
> /Contacts/({company_id|id)?}

3. Angular service at the front-end

Currently, to populate a table (html table), the service sends a HTTP Get to one of the APIs, then the backend calls the db repository (resulting sql call to the DAL), and the data is returned via the service to the browser window.

I would like the cache the data, to minimize the SQL calls (the reason is that the sql server is located not on the LAN, and the application runs in the LAN only).

I can't cache it in the service, since it's client-side cache, and there are multiple users.
I can cache in in the server side, (aka repository) and populating up a Companies list, re-poping it on update and returning it on GET.
I was wondering if there is a better solution? maybe libraries or something?

Comment: A somewhat old article with some suggestions [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeekASPNETWebAPICachingWithCacheCowAndCacheOutput.aspx)

Comment: Sorry if i don't get it, but how can you minimize SQL acces here ? Is there more than one access to the data in the process you provided ?

Comment: Use cache with dependency to sql changes, and for the client you can use a solution from here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986907/push-notification-mechanism-between-a-server-and-a-client-app

Cache - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568178/sql-caching-and-entity-framework

Comment: @stephen.vakil great, I think that is what I'm looking for.
AntoinePelletier, 2 HTTP gets will require 2 sql server SELECTs for example, 1 for each get.
ZivWeissman, sorry but what is cache with dependency?